# TCP/IP trafic not coming to my client

Tags: sockets, tcp

I am using IBM Integration Bus TCP adaptor to interact with an external system. I create a client connection. I send data to the server and expect data as response. I find that the response does not come after sometime. My throughput is 1 or 2 TPS. I get only 60 bytes responses.

```
====( 60 bytes received on interface en0 )==== 16:17:40.933244582
ETHERNET packet : [ 74:26:ac:6b:08:c6 -> 6c:ae:8b:68:dc:1c ]  type 800  (IP)
IP header breakdown:
    < SRC = 192.168.114.140 >  
    < DST =     10.0.249.12 > 
    ip_v=4, ip_hl=20, ip_tos=0, ip_len=40, ip_id=51164, ip_off=0
    ip_ttl=56, ip_sum=84b2, ip_p = 6 (TCP)
TCP header breakdown:
    <source port=7113, destination port=60048 >
    th_seq=3151777438, th_ack=1975140464
    th_off=5, flags<PUSH | ACK>
    th_win=65535, th_sum=b28b, th_urp=0
```

Once i bounce the IIB adapter I start getting the data and then it stops after sometime.

The same is working in a different environments. All the parameters and settings are same in the two set ups. Only thing different is that they are in different cities.

Comment: Please include expected response in your question as well as any relevant configuration settings.

Comment: HiMy expectation is as follows. 1, What could have caused this. why am i not getting the packets, is there any problem due to the TCP buffer being full. are there any other config changes that i need to do.